# Assigning values to duplicate row in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Exist dataframe with

```
Customer  Score
3a62-4799  500
3a62-4799   NA
3a62-1234   450
3a62-1234   NA
```

How to find all duplicate with customer and copy score to NA value.

I tried this approach

```
X['Score'][((X.set_index('Customer').index.get_duplicates()) & (X['Score']>0)).any()] =X['Score']
```

But it doesn’t work

> ValueError: Arrays were different lengths:

Answer (score 7):

I think you can use [`ffill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.ffill.html) with [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) if in each group is only first no NaN value:

```
print (df)
    Customer  Score
0  3a62-4000    NaN
1  3a62-4799  500.0
2  3a62-4799    NaN
3  3a62-1234  450.0
4  3a62-1234    NaN

df.loc[df.Customer.duplicated(keep=False), 'Score'] = df.Score.ffill()
print (df)
    Customer  Score
0  3a62-4000    NaN
1  3a62-4799  500.0
2  3a62-4799  500.0
3  3a62-1234  450.0
4  3a62-1234  450.0
```

If multiple values per groups you can fill duplicates by `mean` (`sum`, `median`...) with [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) or [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html):

```
print (df)
    Customer  Score
0  3a62-4000    NaN
1  3a62-4799  500.0
2  3a62-4799  200.0
3  3a62-4799    NaN
4  3a62-1234  450.0
5  3a62-1234    NaN

df['Score'] = df.groupby('Customer')['Score'].transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))
#df['Score'] = df.groupby('Customer')['Score'].apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))
print (df)
    Customer  Score
0  3a62-4000    NaN
1  3a62-4799  500.0
2  3a62-4799  200.0
3  3a62-4799  350.0
4  3a62-1234  450.0
5  3a62-1234  450.0
```

Comment: Very nice solution. Thanks!

Comment: Nice solution.  Plus one

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you might use `groupby` to forward fill for each customer ID.

```
df.Score = df.groupby('Customer').ffill()
```

Using the data set from @jezreal's answer, the output would be

```
df
Out[10]: 
    Customer  Score
0  3a62-4000    NaN
1  3a62-4799    500
2  3a62-4799    500
3  3a62-1234    450
4  3a62-1234    450
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately values are mixed sometimes NaN first in duplicate rows sometimes real value is first.

My approach for 100000 rows is working for 30 min. it's a little bit longer

```
X_dup = X.set_index('Customer').index.get_duplicates()

for l in list(X_dup):

    up_cust = pd.DataFrame(X[(X['Customer']==l) & (X['Score'] > 0)])

    X['Score'][X['Customer']==l ] = up_cust.iloc[0,1]
```